# Error while passing array in merge sort in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge sort algorithm in c++ but I keep getting a compilation error which I am to unable to overcome.

Here is the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void sort(int a[],int l,int r,int b[]){

    int mid=(l+r)/2;
    int L[mid-l],R[r-mid];
    if((r-l)==1)
    b[0]=a[l];
    else if((r-l)>1){

        sort(a,l,mid,L);
        sort(a,mid,r,R);
        merge(L,(mid-l),R,(r-mid),b);
    }

    return;
}

void merge(int a[],int n,int b[],int m,int c[]){

    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(k<(m+n)){
        if(j==m||(a[i]<=b[j]&&i<n)){
            c[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else if(i==n||(b[j]<a[i]&&j<m)){
            c[k]=b[j];
            j++;  
            k++;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main(){

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n],b[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(a,0,n,b);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I keep getting is that I can't pass the array b[] from sort function to merge function.

Please help me correct the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to declare merge before you call it. And you need not to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.

Comment: `cin>>n; int a[n]` In C++, the size of an array must be a compile time constant.

Comment: thanks i didn't realize this as i have only recently switched from java to c++ and was unaware of this.

Comment: @SiddharthKapoor *thanks i didn't realize this as i have only recently switched from java to c++* -- What didn't you realize exactly?  There are at least two things wrong with your code, function declaration and usage of `int a[n]`.  Also, don't call your function `sort`, as there already exists a `std::sort` in the `<algorithm>` header, and I don't know what that `bits/stdc++.h` has in it.

Comment: In java it doesn't matter if we declare the merge function before or after the sort function. As for bits/stdc++.h I use it only because I don't need to import other libraries as I am unable to remember them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `merge` before calling it. That means, you need to declare it before `sort`. For example -

```
void merge(int a[],int n,int b[],int m,int c[]);
```

Write this declaration before the definition of `sort`

*EDIT* I just figured out another error in this line

```
int a[n],b[n]
```

You cannot do this. In C++ the size of array must be a compile time constant.

Comment: Thanks, but my code works just fine after I declared merge function before the sort function. The 2nd correction had no effect on the code and I didn't even get any warning or error messages